# Extended initializer lists and arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, initializer-list

I have simple function such as:

```
void fun(vector<int> vec)
{
//...
}

void fun(int* smth)
{
//...
}
```

No when i write in my program.

```
fun({2,3});
```

It calls me fun with vector argument i know it is in new C++ extended initializer lists but i would like to use new C++ and tell compiler that this is only a array of int's how i can do it?

EDIT:

It would be nice to do it in 1 line :)

Comment: You can't have temporary arrays in C++, (un)fortunately.

Comment: @kerrek incorrect. i annoyed the committee in madrid until they accepted them into C++11.

Comment: `It would be nice to do it in 1 line :)` Why's that?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: I never knew - which part of the standard is that?

Comment: @KerrekSB there is no particularly part. it just is not disallowed. i emailed that there were several paragraphs not forbidding certain uses of temporary arrays and other paragraphs partially contradicting each other. And it was decided to get rid of all rules that forbid or that are in the way of temporary arrays.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't initialise a pointer with an array, because a pointer is not an array (despite the appearance in *some* situations that this is occuring, it is not).

You'll have to pass a pointer to a pre-existing array. Alternatively, use the `vector` overload — surely, you prefer this one anyway?! And if the two functions do different things then why are they overloads of one another (i.e. *why does it matter*)?

Comment: passing a pointer to a preexisting array will initialize a pointer with an array, will it not?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: No. It will populate the pointer with the address of the first element of the array, before initialising the argument's pointer with this pointer. At no stage is anything being initialised with an array other than the actual array itself.

Answer (score 6):

Make an alias template

```
template<typename T>
using identity = T;
```

So you can write

```
fun(identity<int[]>{1,2});
```

---

This is not good programming though, because in your function you have no way to know the size of the array pointed to. This should be passed explicitly to the function, if the function is supposed to work with a list of elements. If you want to process arrays, consider using something like `llvm::ArrayRef<T>` or create your own

```
struct array_ref {
public:
  template<int N>
  array_ref(const identity<int[N]> &n)
    :begin_(n), end_(n + N)
  { }

  array_ref(const std::vector<int>& n)
    :begin_(n.data()), end_(n.data() + n.size())
  { }

public:
  int const *begin() const { return begin_; }
  int const *end() const { return end_; }
  int size() const { return end_ - begin_; }

private:
  int const *begin_;
  int const *end_;
};

void fun(array_ref array) {
  ...
}

int main() {
  fun(array_ref(identity<int[]>{1,2}));
}
```

Comment: But this shouldn't be necessary. The vector overload should do the same thing, so the OP should become satisfied with using it!

Comment: @light no the vector overload will allocate dynamic memory. there are environments where this is a nogo.

Comment: What do you suppose the likelihood is that that's a serious consideration in this case?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbiti i have no idea.

Comment: `array_ref` and `basic_string_ref` were [proposed for standardization](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3334.html), so hopefully we'll see them in C++14. :-)

Comment: Can someone explain why `fun(identity<int[]>{1,2})` is correct? IMHO the array should get destructed right after the pointer got initialized.

Comment: @ipc it has full-expression lifetime.